# DAO Best practices : Querying Parent / Children

Tags: database, language-agnostic, dao

Given you have a domain model with a simple parent / child relationship, and each entity has it's own associated DAO, eg:

```
Author
AuthorDAO
Book
BookDAO
```

If I want to add a DAO method for retrieving the books by a specific author, what's the best place for it?

```
class AuthorDAO
{
    List<Book> getBooks(Author author);
}
```

or

```
class BookDAO
{
    List<Book> getBooks(Author author)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd place a `Book` *finder* on the `BookDAO`. This is where I would expect it to be, regardless of its parameters. If you want to find a book, you don't want to scan all DAOs to find where the right finder is. Putting it somewhere else won't help the users of the API.

Answer (score 3):

The `BookDAO`, because you want to get information about books. The `Book` is the main subject here.